# Контейнер set

Tags: c++

Помогите разобраться с контейнером set. Прочитав Лафоре ничего не понял, кроме элементарного. По заданию нужно массивы закидывать в множества, то есть создать массив setов.

Comment: Хочу понять, как мне закидывать в мои сеты массивы и как потом с ними работать. Какого типа будет массив сетов? И хотя бы один понятный пример увидеть.

Comment: Вот вам пример:

    std::vector<int> v{ 1, 3, 5, 3, 1 };
    std::set<int> s(begin(v), end(v));
    for (auto& e : s)
        cout << e << endl;

([Выведет 1, 3, 5.](http://ideone.com/h6fLS4))

Comment: Множество массивов — это совсем не то, что массив множеств.

У первого тип `std::set< std::vector<T> >`, а у второго, понятно, `std::vector< std::set<T> >` (`T` — тип элементов.)

Comment: А можете прокомментировать? И как мне работать с массивом множеств? С помощью итераторов?

Comment: Ну, там же самоочевидно:

    std::vector<int> v{ 1, 3, 5, 3, 1 }; // создали вектор из 5 элементов
    std::set<int> s(begin(v), end(v));   // элементы вектора положили в множество
    for (auto& e : s)                    // для каждого элемента множества ...
        cout << e << endl;               // ... вывели его на консоль

С массивом множеств работать надо так же, как и с любым массивом. Хоть с помощью итераторов, хоть индексируя, хоть через `#include <algorithm>`, как угодно.

Comment: Понял, спасибо огромное

Comment: Я пробовал так, все равно. не хочу переходить из-за того, что там нет форм.

Comment: @triathlet23: У вас старый компилятор, обновите его. Если обновиться совсем не судьба, пишите

    for (std::set<int>::const_iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
        cout << *it << endl;

(Да, некрасиво, устаревший синтаксис.)

---
Тогда делайте тупо:

    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(10);
    v.push_back(20);
    v.push_back(30);

Или [так](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2236197/276994) (магия!):

    const int arr[] = {1, 3, 5};
    vector<int> v(arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]));